# Cucumber leaf turn to yellow , why?

Tags: indoors

[image]

5 times water per day 
Each time =3 minutes 
Can someone help with that 
Thank you !

Comment: Which kind of soil. Did you fertilize the soil?

Comment: you're watering too much

Comment: Where are you in the world and are these cucumbers in pots or in the ground?

Comment: You are watering too much.  Feel the heft of your pot and soil and plant when watered.  Until that pot is easily lifted because it is light it should not be watered.  Watering once per day is normal depending on the soil you've used and type of plant and the size of pot.  Did you use potting soil if you planted in pots?  Otherwise, watering once per day is too much for plants in the large body of garden soil.  5X per day?  Use a few cat food or tuna cans with straight sides.  1/4 inch out of an inch necessary per week.   Pot or garden.

Comment: Definitely you MUST use some balanced fertilizer.

Answer (score 3):

Chlorosis or yellowing of the leaves suggests a nutrient deficiency.  If it's occurring in the new leaves then it's from a fixed nutrient.  If it's appearing in the older leaves, it's from a mobile nutrient such as nitrogen.

If you're watering 5 times a day you may be washing the nutrients out of the potting mix so that you're starving the plant.

I'd suggest applying a balanced vegetable fertilizer to see if you can remediate the damage.  And water only if your potting mix gets dry.  They only need an inch a week.

Comment: Graham Chiu, I can see how five times a day may seem excessive, and how it could flush nutrients out, but in some areas, and with some soil types, in containers or out, the soil will dry out much more quickly than you suggest, with watering an inch a week. But, yeah, the questioner didn't give us information on the growing conditions beyond watering frequency.

Comment: Got to work with what we have which isn't much.